# getting Max and count together in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to get maximum holiday column and id related to the max holidays...how do i tweak the query?

```
select cal.schoolid,count(d.instruction) as holiday 
    from day d 
    inner join calendar cal on d.calendarID=cal.calendarID
    inner join schoolyear sy on sy.endyear=cal.endyear and sy.active=1
    where d.instruction=0 
    group by cal.schoolid
```

HERE is the result:

```
ID  Holidays
237 86
240 86
261 168
262 168
264 155
266 168
267 170
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Top 1` to get the `Max Holiday`

```
SELECT TOP 1 cal.schoolid,
                Count(d.instruction) AS holiday
         FROM   [day] d
                INNER JOIN calendar cal
                        ON d.calendarID = cal.calendarID
                INNER JOIN schoolyear sy
                        ON sy.endyear = cal.endyear
                           AND sy.active = 1
         WHERE  d.instruction = 0
         GROUP  BY cal.schoolid
ORDER  BY Holiday DESC
```

Or use `Window Function`

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT cal.schoolid,
                Count(d.instruction) AS holiday
         FROM   [day] d
                INNER JOIN calendar cal
                        ON d.calendarID = cal.calendarID
                INNER JOIN schoolyear sy
                        ON sy.endyear = cal.endyear
                           AND sy.active = 1
         WHERE  d.instruction = 0
         GROUP  BY cal.schoolid)
SELECT ID,
       Holidays
FROM  (SELECT Row_number()OVER (ORDER BY Holidays DESC) rn,*
       FROM   cte) A
WHERE  rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The result somehow is different from what you are selecting (I mean the column names). Anyway, use `MAX()`:

```
select cal.schoolid,MAX(count(d.instruction)) as holiday 
from day d 
inner join calendar cal on d.calendarID=cal.calendarID
inner join schoolyear sy on sy.endyear=cal.endyear and sy.active=1
where d.instruction=0
group by cal.schoolid
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 select schoolid, max(holiday) from( select cal.schoolid,count(d.instruction) as
holiday 
from day d 
inner join calendar cal on d.calendarID=cal.calendarID
inner join schoolyear sy on sy.endyear=cal.endyear and sy.active=1
where d.instruction=0 
group by cal.schoolid) group by schoolid
```